# python tkinter self error

Tags: python, object, tkinter, self

this is probably something really trivial.

I am getting the following error.

```
"self.d = {'Roosevelt Bridge': {"Monday": final()}}
TypeError: final() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'"
```

if I skip the dictionary, everything else works fine without error.  I don't know how to add the dictionary type object into tkinter.

thanks for some clarity.

```
import tkinter as tk


def main():

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("class basic window")
    root.geometry("250x350")
    root.config(background="LightBlue4")
    app = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()


class Application(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="ivory2", bd=2, 
        relief=tk.RAISED)
        self.parent = parent
        self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):
        self.grid()


        self.optionList=["", "repair", "boat crossing", "mechinical   
                         issue", "accident"]
        self.dropVar=tk.StringVar()
        self.dropVar.set(self.optionList[0])
        self.dropMenu=tk.OptionMenu(self, self.dropVar,      
                      *self.optionList)
        self.dropMenu.config(width=10)
        self.dropMenu.pack()


        self.get=tk.Button(self, text="update", command=self.final)
        self.get.pack()
        #self.pack(fill=t.BOTH, expand=1)


    def final(self):

        if self.dropVar.get()==self.optionList[0]:
            return ("1")

        else:
            return ("0")

        self.d = {'Roosevelt Bridge': {"Monday": final()}}

        print (self.d)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Right now it's hard to see which code is in which scope/method.

Comment: what do really want to achieve.

Comment: What is `self.d = {'Roosevelt Bridge': {"Monday": final()}}` supposed to do` Call `final()` again? How is this supposed not to lead to infinite recursion, given that `final` does not alter any of the values that could make the recursion stop?

Comment: {"Monday": self.final} ???

Comment: @Lafexlos.  as far as a beginner goes, I think i fixed the indentation now.  Unless my indentation is wrong too.

Comment: @AD WAN  I was trying to get the value from the dropdown list to update the nested dictionary, but instead of the actual value from the dropdown list, i only want a 1 or a 0.  i have a further process that  i already written in pulp and now working on the GUI part.  the print statement is just a way for me to make sure the function final() is working to update the value of the dictionary.  since it's giving me an error, that's why i need help.

Answer (score 0):

This has a **very** simple answer all you need to do is change the line with the error to

`self.d = {'Roosevelt Bridge': {"Monday": final(self)}}`

It's exactly the same apart from the fact at were it said `final()` I changed it to `final(self)` then it worked fine!

Hope this helps!

Comment: hi @Guydangerous99 I did you try your code and it still gives me an error "self.d = {'Roosevelt Bridge': {"Monday": final(self)}}
NameError: name 'self' is not defined"  however as Lafexios says, it might have to do with indentation. i moved the self.d.... as the same alignment as the if else statement and it didn't give me any error, the only thing is my print statement is not working and says the same "self is not defined".  this gives me a conclusion, where can I put this "self.d" nested dict in the program? thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  It turned out I was confused with scope of the variable d, and the function final.  here is the code that works the way that I wanted to work.  thanks for the questions and the contribution for my learning.

```
import tkinter as tk
```

D = {'Roosevelt Bridge': {"Monday": 1}}

def main():

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("class basic window")
root.geometry("250x350")
root.config(background="LightBlue4")
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

class Application(tk.Frame):

```
def __init__(self, parent):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="ivory2", bd=2, relief=tk.RAISED)   
    self.parent = parent
    self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
    self.initUI()


def initUI(self):
    self.grid()


    self.optionList=["", "repair", "boat crossing", "mechinical issue", "accident"]
    self.dropVar=tk.StringVar()
    self.dropVar.set(self.optionList[0])
    self.dropMenu=tk.OptionMenu(self, self.dropVar, *self.optionList)
    self.dropMenu.config(width=10)
    self.dropMenu.pack()

    self.get=tk.Button(self, text="update", command=self.update)
    self.get.pack()
    #self.pack(fill=t.BOTH, expand=1)


def final(self):

    if self.dropVar.get()==self.optionList[0]:
        return ("1")

    else:
        return ("0")

def update(self):

    global D
    D = {'Roosevelt Bridge': {"Monday": self.final()}}
    print (D)
```

if **name** == '**main**':
    main()